# Is there a characterization of graphs without a K6 minor? (or no K6, K3,4 minor?) Maybe similar to planarity?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs

It is known that planar graphs are those graphs having no K5 and K3,3 minor. Similarly, outerplanar graphs are those that have no K4 and K2,3 minors.

However, what about those graphs that have no K6 minor? Or no K3,4 minor, or neither of them?

I have found [here](https://books.google.at/books?id=JUeqCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA63-IA84&lpg=PA63-IA84&dq=no+k6+minor&source=bl&ots=-wxc_Vmx__&sig=ACfU3U0dDOLyx5gvsdZk6h9tiJ2HxtwONA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikqeuz9rzpAhXTkFwKHb0cBxMQ6AEwAXoECAoQAQ#v=onepage&q=no%20k6%20minor&f=false) that maybe there is no characterization so far for having no K6 minor?

Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned in your link, there is the famous [Hadwiger conjecture][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger_conjecture_(graph_theory)] saying that the graphs with no $K_t$ minors are $t-1$-colorable (with chromatic number strictly less than $t$).  It's a generalisation of the 4 colours theorem and the $K_5$ case. 

That would be the best conjecture about characterisation of graphs with no $K_6$ minors : there are 5 colorable.